# Adding GreenDao LazyList into a list is not possible?

Tags: android, greendao

I have a huge database and I am trying to perform the pagination using Limit and offset options in greendao.

what I want to do is , appending the new coming results in the list consist of first 20 results fetched from database using greenDao query builder ,,

**Here is how I am doing it**

```
QueryBuilder qb = employeeDao.queryBuilder();
        qb.limit(20).offset(20*pageNum).orderDesc(EmployeeDao.Properties.Id);
        qb.build().forCurrentThread();
        List<Employee> tempEmployeeList = qb.list();
        employeeList.addAll(tempEmployeeList); // error occurred here
```

The employeeList is a list which contains the list of first 20 employee Details. Now I want to know how can I add this ,

**Below is the error I am getting**

> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
>                                                                                         at org.greenrobot.greendao.query.LazyList.addAll(LazyList.java:205)
>                                                                                         at com.naziraschool.employeemanager.fragments.FragEmployeeList.refreshFragEmployeeListData(FragEmployeeList.java:294)

**Questions:**

1. Why I can not addAll the list of same data type which is (employee in my case)
2. How i can append the list(coming from query builder) into previous list (employee list)

Please Help

Comment: how many employees do you expect to have? 1000s? 10,000s? 100,000s? more?

Comment: i dont know ,  let say infinite , user will add as many employee he want to

Comment: use [this](https://github.com/path/android-priority-jobqueue/blob/master/examples/twitter/TwitterClient/src/com/path/android/jobqueue/examples/twitter/adapters/LazyListAdapter.java) adapter then

Comment: what it works ?

Comment: adapter, the adapter i posted a link to, did you try it? with this adapter you dont need to "paginate" anything

Comment: let me take a look at it

Comment: @pskink how can I use it with my custom adapter of recycler view

Comment: it is designed for a `ListView` as it extends `BaseAdapter`, you would need to adapt the same concept for `RecyclerView.Adapter`, it should take less than 5 minutes (only `getItemCount()` needs to be implemented)

Comment: that is good, I should use it . well I am able to do it , using some things in green dao. see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well its pretty simple , All we need to do is to use the limit() with the provided function of offset() as stated [here](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/queries/#Limit_Offset_and_Pagination) .

Now its a pretty simple but as there is no such example given on page so it creates the problem to the newbie of greendao user.

First we need to understand what is limit and offset mean when used together. 
well Limit() is pretty simple to understand that it will return mentioned amount of data everytime . let say it will return 10 records if we have mentioned Limit(10) .

so now have a look at offset with limit .

> use something like LIMIT x OFFSET y where x is the number of rows you want to retrieve at a time and y is your offset you want to start retrieving results from.

i read that on SO , and its really helped me in building the pagination logic for me . I used [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView) for implementing the endless recyclerview . And subsequently I added logic for pagination in onLoadMore function of EndlessRecyclerViewScrollListener.

What I did is some thing like this

```
 QueryBuilder qb = employeeDao.queryBuilder();
        qb.limit(10).offset(10*pageNum).orderDesc(EmployeeDao.Properties.Id);
        qb.build().forCurrentThread();
        List<Employee> tempEmployeeList = qb.list();
        employeeList.addAll(tempEmployeeList);
```

where pageNum is a integer value incremented everytime by 1 when onLoadMore is called. so at firs pageNum variable has a value of 1 then 2 and so on. ...

I hope this will help some one in Understanding a little though.